# What is the benefit of using .on event in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events

What is the benefit of using the .on event in jQuery as opposed to just using the .event? For example, using a mouseenter event:

```
$(element).on("mouseenter", function(){ code; });
```

as opposed to:

```
$(element).mouseenter(function(){ code; });
```

Comment: A more consistent API, the ability to dynamically choose which event to bind to, the option for delegating the event to a parent DOM element, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To get the full answer you will need to check the doc on http://api.jquery.com/on/

For me the first thing come to mind about when to use 'on' is when html come dynamically by ajax request for example and html get rendered after the full page load with js is done.
On will bind events to new elements which come dynamically on the page.
Which is the same behavior as '[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)' in previous jquery versions regarding this ajax issues.

For full answer I recommend reading the doc and its examples.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out.  Seems to me that On is a very dynamic method.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach multiple events to the same function using on

```
$(element).on("mouseenter click", function(){ code; });
```

This is probably more readable then using the shorthand version for each event
(This is just one benefit.)

Answer (score 0):

The method `.on()` has an extra parameter available: `selector`.

This means that you can bind an event to a parent element, but only trigger on certain child elements. This can mean that creating DOM elements through JavaScript do not require subsequent attaching of events.

An example:

```
$(document).on(
    'click',
    'span',
    function () { console.log('Span clicked'); }
);

$(function () {
    // Both the below spans will have the above click handler
    // attached even though they are created after the click
    // handler itself.

    $('body').append('<span>Span 1</span>');
    $('body').append('<span>Span 2</span>');
});
```

Comment: I see.  So one benefit is not having to define a new event handler for subsequent elements that I would like to bind to.  Instead, using the .on() method to define event handling for desired elements only one time.  It also seems that being able to target child elements while binding to a parent element is much easier to do with .on() as well.  THANKS!

Answer (score -1):

the event of `$(element).mouseenter(function(){ code; });` have some bug 
recently i want to to use this for many button that i made dynamically by PHP
on webpage ,this event didn't work
and use "on" event and it's working

Comment: this is not a bug, this is the different between on style and without.